# Apache 2.4.25 some headers being stripped in proxied request

Tags: apache, http-headers, mod-proxy

I am proxying requests from server A (Apache 2.4) to server B (Apache 2.2) as following:

```
RequestHeader set X_REMOTE_USER  %{REMOTE_USER}s
ProxyPass / https://www.server_b.com/
ProxyPassReverse / https://www.server_b.com/
```

When I print the environment variables on server B, I see `HTTP_X_REMOTE_USER`.  However, when I do the same proxying to server C (Apache 2.4), apache doesn't set an environment variable with that name.

It appears that going from 2.2 to 2.4 some of the environment variables set from request headers are no longer being set. Is this correct? If so, how do I make 2.4 work like 2.2?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `SetEnvIf` to set an environment variable based on a request header. For example:

```
SetEnvIf X_REMOTE_USER "^(.*)$" HTTP_X_REMOTE_USER=$1
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit further what this is doing and where to place it?